# How to accept Firebase Properties Google Analytics updated Terms of Service of hosting only project (no apps)?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have more than a dozen Firebase projects, some of them are hosting-only (without any attached apps), a few of them has apps too (usually any mobile app I have has a companion website and sometimes the app can even interact with its website). Each website has Google Analytics property created and associated with (not via Firebase, but via Google Analytics).

Firebase started to warn us to accept updated Google Analytics Terms of Service. Today it's a final notice:

> This is the final reminder that you own one or more Firebase projects using Google Analytics that have not accepted the updated Terms of Service. Accepting the Terms is required to continue using Google Analytics.

I could accept the updated ToS for those few projects where Firebase hosted website has a companion app as well. But any other website which is hosting only does not offer that.

[image: Firebase Google Analytics]

I don't have any companion app (no iOS app, no Android app, no webapp, no Unity app) for those so how would I overcome that and get to the ToS accept dialog so I can select my GA property and get this over with?

> If the terms are still not accepted by March 15th, 2022, we will permanently delete these properties and their data.

(I guess they mean the GA properties here. I don't want that.)

Answer (score 0):

My situation may be different but I could accept conditions following [these instructions](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/P735VAsqpCM/m/0kALFBkpAQAJ):

> you should be able to look at the Analytics integration settings by opening Settings (gear icon in navigation, "Project settings"), opening the "Integrations" tab, and opening the "Google Analytics" integration card.